# Xamarin: update listview item from async func

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, android-asynctask, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using the Xamarin.Media.Plugin to make photo from camera using the async function `CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync`. If photo have been maked, I need to update listview item. This code working fine, but on the slow devices, updating item is too slow, and if in this time, user changed item in listview, will updating the new item, not previos. How I can fix this?

```
private async void BtnPhoto_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            MediaFile mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(opt);

            if (mediaFile != null)
            {
                Shared.CurrentQuest.Photo[listViewHydromer.CheckedItemPosition] = mediaFile.Path;
                adapter.SetCustomElement("labelPhoto", "Exist");
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                mediaFile.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

CustomAdapter code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

        row = row ?? LayoutInflater
            .From(context)
            .Inflate(Resource.Drawable.hydromerListViewContentLine, null, false);

        //События для контролов
        labelIsPhotoAvailable.Click += (s, e) => ShowPhotoDetails(position);

        //Присваиваем полям значения
        labelId.Text = $"Водомер: {hydromers.ElementAt(position).Id}";
        labelDate.Text = $"Последняя поверка: {hydromers.ElementAt(position).LastDate}";
        labelLastIndication.Text = "Последние показания: ";
        labelCurrentIndication.Text = "Текущие показания: ";

        return row;
    }
```

SetCustomElemetns method:

```
public void SetCustomElement(string element, string value)
    {
        if(element == "labelCurrentIndication")
          labelCurrentIndication.Text = $"Текущие показания: { value}";

        if (element == "labelIsPhotoAvailable")
          labelIsPhotoAvailable.Text = "Фото готово";

    }
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Водомер 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/hydromerListView_LineId" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Последняя поверка:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/hydromerListView_LineLastDate" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Последние показания:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/hydromerListView_LineLastIndication" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Текущие показания:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/hydromerListView_LineCurrentIndication" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="Нет фото"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="65sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingRight="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/hydromerListView_IsPhotoAvailable" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post detailed codes of xaml and your listview adapter?

Comment: @Elvis Xia - MSFT, I have updated my post